# Solving an integral over a given domain - what to do about unwanted division-by-zero singularities?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, limits

I'm attempting to find an integral

$\int_0^l \cos \left(b_1+c_1 d_1 t\right) \cos \left(b_2+c_2 d_2 t\right) \cos \left(b_3+c_3 d_3 t\right) \, dt$

where $l > 0$, $b_{1...3} \neq 0$, $c_{1...3} \neq 0$, and $d_{1...3}$ are parts of a unit vector such that $\sqrt{d_1^2+d_2^2+d_3^2}=1$. Everything is real.

I'm able to get this result

$\frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{\sin \left(b_1-b_2-b_3+c_1 d_1 l-c_2 d_2 l-c_3 d_3 l\right)}{c_1 d_1-c_2 d_2-c_3 d_3}+\frac{\sin
   \left(b_1+b_2-b_3+c_1 d_1 l+c_2 d_2 l-c_3 d_3 l\right)}{c_1 d_1+c_2 d_2-c_3 d_3}+\frac{\sin \left(b_1-b_2+b_3+c_1 d_1 l-c_2 d_2
   l+c_3 d_3 l\right)}{c_1 d_1-c_2 d_2+c_3 d_3}+\frac{\sin \left(b_1+b_2+b_3+c_1 d_1 l+c_2 d_2 l+c_3 d_3 l\right)}{c_1 d_1+c_2
   d_2+c_3 d_3}-\frac{\sin \left(b_1-b_2-b_3\right)}{c_1 d_1-c_2 d_2-c_3 d_3}-\frac{\sin \left(b_1+b_2-b_3\right)}{c_1 d_1+c_2
   d_2-c_3 d_3}-\frac{\sin \left(b_1-b_2+b_3\right)}{c_1 d_1-c_2 d_2+c_3 d_3}-\frac{\sin \left(b_1+b_2+b_3\right)}{c_1 d_1+c_2
   d_2+c_3 d_3}\right)$

However, the fractions mean this has a limited domain defined by

$c_1 d_1-c_2 d_2-c_3 d_3\neq 0\land c_1 d_1+c_2 d_2-c_3 d_3\neq 0\land c_1 d_1-c_2 d_2+c_3 d_3\neq 0\land c_1 d_1+c_2 d_2+c_3
   d_3\neq 0$

Which is not the same as the one I specified above. **Is there a way that I can get a result that's valid for my entire desired domain?** If at all possible, I need the result to be in a non-piecewise form, as I need to evaluate many of these in an environment with poor piecewise support.

---

#### Additional info that may or may not be relevant

I need to do many expressions of this form, and I'm actually evaluating them in two stages.

I have a data set of values for $b_{1...3}$ and $c_{1...3}$. In the first stage, I'm substituting those in, such that I end up with a list of expressions parameterised by only $d_{1...3}$ and $l$. The terms involving only those substituted values will be turned into constants at that stage. I (well, Mathematica) can do additional rearrangements after those substitutions. I'm unsure whether knowing those substituted values helps to avoid my domain issues.

I'll then be evaluating each of those expressions many times for different values of $d_{1...3}$ and $l$.

Comment: Since you've already gone through the incredibly tedious process of deriving the integral, why not just split it into cases where, for example, $c_1d_1=c_2d_2+c_3d_3$, then evaluate the integral again? Very tedious, yes, but hardly much more tedious than what you are have.